# How to move inside a list while copy to another list with Java Swing ?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlist

I have the following program which can either copy or move items between 2 lists, I want to use this as a base to develop a DJ program to play music.
The right list would be a list of available songs reading from a directory on my PC, the left list holds the songs I want to play.

So when I drag and drop a song from right to left list, it will be added to the list of songs to be played, but when I d&d a song from left to right, it should just remove it from the play list on the left side while not affecting the list of songs in the right list which was read from local drive. And when I d&d a song in the left list it just reorders the play list, so how to change it so that :

```
[1] When I drag and drop an item in the left list, it moves the item inside the list
[2] When I drag and drop an item from the left list to the right list, it only removes it from left list while does nothing to the right list
[3] When I drag and drop an item from the right list to the left list, it only adds the item to the left list while does nothing to the right list.

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public final class Demo_Drag_And_Drop_List_Panel extends JPanel                // http://ateraimemo.com/Swing/DnDBetweenLists.html
{
  static JRadioButton Copy_Button=new JRadioButton("Copy"),Move_Button=new JRadioButton("Move");

  private Demo_Drag_And_Drop_List_Panel()
  {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel p=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,10,0));
    TransferHandler h=new ListItemTransferHandler();
    TitledBorder title=BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Drag & Drop between JLists");
    p.setBorder(title);
    title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
    p.add(new JScrollPane(makeList(h)));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(makeList(h)));
    add(p);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,260));

    JPanel Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel=new JPanel();

    Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel.add(Copy_Button);

    Move_Button.setSelected(true);
    Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel.add(Move_Button);

    //Group the radio buttons.
    ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(Copy_Button);
    group.add(Move_Button);

    add("South",Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel);
  }

  private static JList<Color> makeList(TransferHandler handler)
  {
    DefaultListModel<Color> listModel=new DefaultListModel<>();
    listModel.addElement(Color.RED);
    listModel.addElement(Color.BLUE);
    listModel.addElement(Color.GREEN);
    listModel.addElement(Color.CYAN);
    listModel.addElement(Color.ORANGE);
    listModel.addElement(Color.PINK);
    listModel.addElement(Color.MAGENTA);
    JList<Color> list=new JList<>(listModel);
    list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer()
    {
      @Override public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus)
      {
        Component c=super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
        ((JLabel)c).setForeground((Color)value);
        return c;
      }
    });
    list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
    list.setDragEnabled(true);
    list.setTransferHandler(handler);

    ActionMap map=list.getActionMap();
    AbstractAction dummy=new AbstractAction()                                  // Disable row Cut, Copy, Paste
    {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      { /* Dummy action */ }
    };
    map.put(TransferHandler.getCutAction().getValue(Action.NAME),dummy);
    map.put(TransferHandler.getCopyAction().getValue(Action.NAME),dummy);
    map.put(TransferHandler.getPasteAction().getValue(Action.NAME),dummy);

    return list;
  }

  public static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
//    try { UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); }
//    catch (ClassNotFoundException|InstantiationException|IllegalAccessException|UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Demo_Drag_And_Drop_List_Panel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Demo_Drag_And_Drop_List_Panel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); }
    });
  }
}

class ListItemTransferHandler extends TransferHandler                          // Demo - BasicDnD (Drag and Drop and Data Transfer)>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/basicdemo.html
{
  private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor;
  private JList source;
  private int[] indices;
  private int addIndex=-1;                                                     // Location where items were added
  private int addCount;                                                        // Number of items added.

  public ListItemTransferHandler()
  {
    super();
    localObjectFlavor=new ActivationDataFlavor(Object[].class,DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType,"Array of items");
  }

  @Override protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
  {
    source=(JList)c;
    indices=source.getSelectedIndices();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") Object[] transferedObjects=source.getSelectedValues();
    return new DataHandler(transferedObjects,localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
  }

  @Override public boolean canImport(TransferSupport info) { return info.isDrop()&&info.isDataFlavorSupported(localObjectFlavor); }

  @Override public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
  {
    return Demo_Drag_And_Drop_List_Panel.Copy_Button.isSelected()?COPY:MOVE;   // TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override public boolean importData(TransferSupport info)
  {
    if (!canImport(info)) return false;
    TransferHandler.DropLocation tdl=info.getDropLocation();
    if (!(tdl instanceof JList.DropLocation)) return false;
    JList.DropLocation dl=(JList.DropLocation)tdl;
    JList target=(JList)info.getComponent();
    DefaultListModel listModel=(DefaultListModel)target.getModel();
    int index=dl.getIndex();
    //boolean insert = dl.isInsert();
    int max=listModel.getSize();
    if (index<0||index>max) index=max;
    addIndex=index;

    try
    {
      Object[] values=(Object[])info.getTransferable().getTransferData(localObjectFlavor);
      for (int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
      {
        int idx=index++;
        listModel.add(idx,values[i]);
        target.addSelectionInterval(idx,idx);
      }
      addCount=target.equals(source)?values.length:0;
      return true;
    }
    catch (UnsupportedFlavorException|IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    return false;
  }

  @Override protected void exportDone(JComponent c,Transferable data,int action) { cleanup(c,action==MOVE); }

  private void cleanup(JComponent c,boolean remove)
  {
    if (remove && indices!=null)
    {
      // If we are moving items around in the same list, we need to adjust the indices accordingly, since those after the insertion point have moved.
      if (addCount>0)
      {
        for (int i=0;i<indices.length;i++) if (indices[i]>=addIndex) indices[i]+=addCount;
      }
      JList source=(JList)c;
      DefaultListModel model=(DefaultListModel)source.getModel();
      for (int i=indices.length-1;i>=0;i--) model.remove(indices[i]);
    }
    indices=null;
    addCount=0;
    addIndex=-1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use the TransferHandler for both lists, they have different requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a `Component#setName(String)` and `Component#getName()`:

> [2] When I drag and drop an item from the left list to the right list,
>   it only removes it from left list while does nothing to the right list

```
if ("songs-right-list".equals(target.getName())
   && "play-left-list".equals(source.getName())) {
  return true;
}
```

> [3] When I drag and drop an item from the right list to the left list,
>   it only adds the item to the left list while does nothing to the right
>   list.

```
if ("play-left-list".equals(target.getName())
    && "songs-right-list".equals(source.getName())) {
  indices = null;
}
```

**DemoDragAndDropListPanel.java**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.activation.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;

public final class DemoDragAndDropListPanel extends JPanel                // http://ateraimemo.com/Swing/DnDBetweenLists.html
{
  static JRadioButton Copy_Button=new JRadioButton("Copy"),Move_Button=new JRadioButton("Move");

  private DemoDragAndDropListPanel()
  {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    JPanel p=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2,10,0));
    TransferHandler h=new ListItemTransferHandler();
    TitledBorder title=BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Drag & Drop between JLists");
    p.setBorder(title);
    title.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
    p.add(new JScrollPane(makeList("play-left-list", h)));
    p.add(new JScrollPane(makeList("songs-right-list", h)));
    add(p);
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,260));

    JPanel Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel=new JPanel();

    Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel.add(Copy_Button);

    Move_Button.setSelected(true);
    Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel.add(Move_Button);

    //Group the radio buttons.
    ButtonGroup group=new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(Copy_Button);
    group.add(Move_Button);

    add("South",Copy_Or_Move_Option_Panel);
  }

  private static JList<Color> makeList(String name, TransferHandler handler)
  {
    DefaultListModel<Color> listModel=new DefaultListModel<>();
    listModel.addElement(Color.RED);
    listModel.addElement(Color.BLUE);
    listModel.addElement(Color.GREEN);
    listModel.addElement(Color.CYAN);
    listModel.addElement(Color.ORANGE);
    listModel.addElement(Color.PINK);
    listModel.addElement(Color.MAGENTA);
    JList<Color> list=new JList<>(listModel);
    list.setName(name);
    list.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer()
    {
      @Override public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,Object value,int index,boolean isSelected,boolean cellHasFocus)
      {
        Component c=super.getListCellRendererComponent(list,value,index,isSelected,cellHasFocus);
        ((JLabel)c).setForeground((Color)value);
        return c;
      }
    });
    list.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
    list.setDropMode(DropMode.INSERT);
    list.setDragEnabled(true);
    list.setTransferHandler(handler);

    ActionMap map=list.getActionMap();
    AbstractAction dummy=new AbstractAction()                                  // Disable row Cut, Copy, Paste
    {
      @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
      { /* Dummy action */ }
    };
    map.put(TransferHandler.getCutAction().getValue(Action.NAME),dummy);
    map.put(TransferHandler.getCopyAction().getValue(Action.NAME),dummy);
    map.put(TransferHandler.getPasteAction().getValue(Action.NAME),dummy);

    return list;
  }

  public static void createAndShowGUI()
  {
//    try { UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()); }
//    catch (ClassNotFoundException|InstantiationException|IllegalAccessException|UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("DemoDragAndDropListPanel");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(new DemoDragAndDropListPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String... args)
  {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
      @Override public void run() { createAndShowGUI(); }
    });
  }
}

class ListItemTransferHandler extends TransferHandler                          // Demo - BasicDnD (Drag and Drop and Data Transfer)>http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/basicdemo.html
{
  private final DataFlavor localObjectFlavor;
  private JList source;
  private int[] indices;
  private int addIndex=-1;                                                     // Location where items were added
  private int addCount;                                                        // Number of items added.

  public ListItemTransferHandler()
  {
    super();
    localObjectFlavor=new ActivationDataFlavor(Object[].class,DataFlavor.javaJVMLocalObjectMimeType,"Array of items");
  }

  @Override protected Transferable createTransferable(JComponent c)
  {
    source=(JList)c;
    indices=source.getSelectedIndices();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") Object[] transferedObjects=source.getSelectedValues();
    return new DataHandler(transferedObjects,localObjectFlavor.getMimeType());
  }

  @Override public boolean canImport(TransferSupport info) { return info.isDrop()&&info.isDataFlavorSupported(localObjectFlavor); }

  @Override public int getSourceActions(JComponent c)
  {
    return DemoDragAndDropListPanel.Copy_Button.isSelected()?COPY:MOVE;   // TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override public boolean importData(TransferSupport info)
  {
    if (!canImport(info)) return false;
    TransferHandler.DropLocation tdl=info.getDropLocation();
    if (!(tdl instanceof JList.DropLocation)) return false;
    JList.DropLocation dl=(JList.DropLocation)tdl;
    JList target=(JList)info.getComponent();
    DefaultListModel listModel=(DefaultListModel)target.getModel();
    int index=dl.getIndex();
    //boolean insert = dl.isInsert();
    int max=listModel.getSize();
    if (index<0||index>max) index=max;
    addIndex=index;

    if ("songs-right-list".equals(target.getName()) && "play-left-list".equals(source.getName())) {
      System.out.println("[2] When I drag and drop an item from the left list to the right list, it only removes it from left list while does nothing to the right list");
      return true;
    }
    try
    {
      Object[] values=(Object[])info.getTransferable().getTransferData(localObjectFlavor);
      for (int i=0;i<values.length;i++)
      {
        int idx=index++;
        listModel.add(idx,values[i]);
        target.addSelectionInterval(idx,idx);
      }
      addCount=target.equals(source)?values.length:0;
      if ("play-left-list".equals(target.getName()) && "songs-right-list".equals(source.getName())) {
        System.out.println("[3] When I drag and drop an item from the right list to the left list, it only adds the item to the left list while does nothing to the right list.");
        indices = null;
      }
      return true;
    }
    catch (UnsupportedFlavorException|IOException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
    return false;
  }

  @Override protected void exportDone(JComponent c,Transferable data,int action) { cleanup(c,action==MOVE); }

  private void cleanup(JComponent c,boolean remove)
  {
    if (remove && indices!=null)
    {
      // If we are moving items around in the same list, we need to adjust the indices accordingly, since those after the insertion point have moved.
      if (addCount>0)
      {
        for (int i=0;i<indices.length;i++) if (indices[i]>=addIndex) indices[i]+=addCount;
      }
      JList source=(JList)c;
      DefaultListModel model=(DefaultListModel)source.getModel();
      for (int i=indices.length-1;i>=0;i--) model.remove(indices[i]);
    }
    indices=null;
    addCount=0;
    addIndex=-1;
  }
}
```

Comment: Wonderful, this is the perfect solution I was looking for, thank you !